# Prove or disprove an inequality involving complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Consider following inequality:

> $|z_1 + z_2|\ge|z_1| - |z_2|  \  \ \ \ \ \  z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

Is that true always? I tried many examples and it was correct but I don't know how to prove that if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that$$\lvert z_1\rvert=\bigl\lvert z_1+z_2+(-z_2)\bigr\rvert\leqslant\lvert z_1+z_2\rvert+\lvert z_2\rvert.$$

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it's true, since $$|z_1+z_2|+|-z_2|\geq|z_1|$$$$|z_1+z_2|\geq|z_1|-|z_2|$$

Comment: The first inequality is false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't know why I reversed the inequality in my head. Doesn't change the triviality of the problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Reverse Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality), say $|z_1\pm z_2|\ge \big||z_1|-|z_2|\big|$.

Then for any real number $|x|\ge x$.